# Lagrange multiplier help (with xy)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I just got this question, and have spent two hours trying to figure out how to solve it, to no avail.

Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum values of the function
$$f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 − 3x − xy$$
on the solid disk $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 9$

If it didn't have that "$xy$" bit in it, it would be super easy to do. But the fact that it does have it throws me off. So I tried it in two different ways.

First:

$$g(t) = 9\cos^2(t) + 9\sin^2(t) - 9\cos(t) - 9\sin(t)\cos(t)$$ in $[0, 2\pi]$, when $x = 3\cos t$ and $y = 3 \sin t$.

The derivative, $g'(t)$, simplifies out to be $9(\sin t + \sin^2 t -\cos^2 t) = 0$ (since I want what t equals) So I basicaly end up with $\sin t + \sin^2 t = \cos^2 t$, and I get stuck. Wolfram alpha says there's multiple answers of $t$, which would be all I need to solve this problem, but I don't know how to get them.

Using lagrange, I get instead  $$\nabla F = (2x - 3 - y, 2y - x)$$ and $$\nabla G = (2x, 2y).$$ Meaning that      $$2x - 3 - y = (\lambda)2x$$     and     $$2y - x = (\lambda)2y$$

Unfortunately, I got stuck there with that method, and can't figure out how to get $x, y$, or $\lambda$ from that.

Can anyone explain how to solve this problem using either of those two methods? Thanks so much!

Comment: You are asked to find the maximum and minimum over the *solid* disk, so this is a two-dimensional calculus problem.  The first approach tries to reduce it to a one-dimensional problem, and that won't work.  Essentially it only considers the outer edge of the disk (circumference).

Comment: Can't I calculate the interior separately by setting the derivatives with respect to x (or y) to 0 and finding solutions that way? And then by comparing the max/mins I get from that with the max/mins I get from the circumference?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  Sorry if I misunderstood your trying in "two different ways".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two regions: $x^2+y^2 <9$ and $x^2+y^2 =9$. Lagrange only works for the second.

For the first use the usual $\nabla F = 0$, while taking care to check if your points $(x,y)$ are inside the circle.

For Lagrange multipliers divide the equation $2x-3-y=2 \lambda x$ by $2y-x = 2 \lambda y$. This yields
$$\frac{2x-3-y}{2y-x} = \frac{x}{y} \text{ and } 2xy -x^2 = 2xy -3y -y^2.$$
Hence $x^2 = y^3 +3y$. Using the restriction $x^2+y^2 = 9$ gives
$$y^2 +3y+y^2 =9.$$
This has as solutions $y=-3$ and $y = 3/2.$ You will find $x=0$ and $x= \pm 3\sqrt{3}/2$. None violate the math we did ($y \neq 0$ and $2y-x \neq 0$) so both are valid solutions.

Take all points you find in the first region, compute the values of the function at these points and you'll discover which are the absolute maximum and minimum.

Comment: Am I missing something? I get x = sqrt(27/4), not 5/2.

Comment: @Notaclue You're correct, I've fixed it.